# I am getting error in IBM Mainframe "DATA SET HELLO.SUYASH.TEST1 NOT ALLOCATED, REQUEST CANCELED"

Tags: mainframe, mvs, tso

I am a new student of IBM z/OS. I want to allocate a NEW DATASET in Utilities > Allocate under ISPF option in "MVS/TSO Module"

I just fill all the required details in this section "Allocate New Data set"  after creating project name in "DATA SET UTILITY" . But when I enter, it's shows the error " DATA SET HELLO.SUYASH.TEST1 NOT ALLOCATED, REQUEST CANCELED ". Here is the screenshot. I also research in Internet but can't get useful information.
Screenshot of my error

[image: 1]

ScreenShot of DataSet

[image: 2]

[image]

Possible Error which I am guessing:-

1. I have done wrong registration which I get COBOL UserId and Password which was given by them after registration in "COBOL Programming with VSCode Registration".[IBM Registration using COBOL](https://www-40.ibm.com/events/wwe/ast/mtm/cobolvscode.nsf/enrollall), Which I want to program in TSO/MVS Mainfram not Cobol programming
2. Some Libraries is missing.
3. Dataset is missing.

I am a new Learner, I am a new  beginner. Please help me to solve this issue as soon as possible so that I can continue my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from that error message, but the first part of a dataset (file) name on the mainframe (the part up to the first period) is called the 'High-level qualifier' or HLQ for short.

Most z/OS sites place fairly strict rules on the HLQs you can use, to prevent the catalog system (how the system knows on which disk it can find which dataset) from being cluttered up with rubbish.

Typical HLQs begin with SYS1, sub-system related HLQs e.g. DB2, CICS, some identifier as to which application they belong to e.g. PAYROLL, BILLING or a user's TSO userid.

'HELLO' seems to be an odd HLQ and there's a good chance that datasets with this HLQ are not allowed and could be rejected by the security system (no-one is allowed to create these files) or some other system checking process.

It could be worth trying to allocate a dataset but don't wrap the dataset in quotes. Then the system might add your 'default' HLQ (usually your TSO userid) onto the front.

Also that message should have a msgid - an identifier on the front that allows you to look up the message and see what it really means. Try entering the command 'TSO MSGID' to turn on msgids, as it appears yours have been turned off.

Addressing your possible errors:

1. You're logged on so that is good.
2. ISPF and TSO are working and I can't think of a missing library that would prevent allocation. People would have noticed
3. The dataset is missing because it isn't even getting created.